# Why is PyCharm seemingly invoking the wrong installation of Python?

Tags: configuration, pycharm, firewall, interpreter

After installing PyCharm 2023.2.3 (Community Edition) I found that all attempts to install Packages were failing with Errors like :

```
Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/scipy/

Package          : scipy
Interpreter Path : C:\Users\{USERNAME}\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version   : Python 3.9.7
```

Assuming a windows firewall issue I made rules to allow outbound connections for PyCharm and the above referenced python.exe but to no avail.

My temporary solution has been to make a firewall rule to allow a previous (stand alone) install of Python to make outbound connections. That version is located at : C:\Users{USERNAME}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe

I'm struggling to understand why PyCharm IDE would favor an 'external' install of Python instead of the included version but then attribute errors to the included version?

1. Is this a bug or have I missed something here?
2. How do I direct Pycharm to use it's included version of Python.exe?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Go to Settings / Project / Python Interpreter. What does it show?

Comment: Hi Reinderien. 
Settings / Project / Python Interpreter shows:
C:\Users\{USERNAME}\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe

Comment: Neither of those is particularly an included or excluded version. One is a venv and one isn't. Check that your program's debug configuration uses the venv as well.